# How to add a new directory to android gallery app

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to have a directory added to the stock android gallery app, and I can't get it to work. I tried the Stock android approach for that, I have also tried the way that is supplied via AOSP and neither have worked. How might I create a new directory, take a new picture and add it to the gallery. I have the photo saving and everything wokring it's just getting it to display in the Gallery app that isn't working

The way google says to add photos to the gallery is the following way....

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

I personally have it set up for

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    Config.context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

where `Config.context`  is initialized in MainActivity to `getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 1):

So I changed my function to the following

```
private void galleryAddPic(String Location) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
    File f = new File(Location);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);

    getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

And to call the function

```
galleryAddPic(image.getAbsolutePath());
```

where image is a `File`

Not the way I had it

```
galleryAddPic("file:"+image.getAbsolutePath());
```